# Selenium CSS "Multiple markers at this line" error

Tags: selenium

I am trying to click on a specific element. I found the cssSelector

```
  [onclick="window.open('../rsvpdemo')"]
```

but when adding it I have ***"Multiple markers at this line"*** remark.

this is my line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[onclick="window.open('../rsvpdemo')"]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes within the string like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[onclick=\"window.open('../rsvpdemo')\"]")).click();
```